# Is it possible to force a complete reset of a local copy of Dropbox?

Tags: macos, dropbox

I have broken Dropbox on my laptop and now it is stuck indexing. Is it possible to delete my local copy of Dropbox completely and force the Dropbox on my laptop to just reset itself with the server?

Previously I put a large number of files into my local Dropbox folder (~1.5 million). Even though they were each very small the upload was taking a long time (it took about 3 - 4 days to upload the first 1 million) so I decided to remove them from my Dropbox and upload zipped copies of the folders instead. When I did this though my Dropbox froze up and started indexing the files I had removed (the ~1.5 million). The index is running very, very slowly (~10^4 files per day during normal use of my laptop) and while it's indexing it does not sync any changes.

At this rate it will take weeks to finish. I have contacted Dropbox support and they said I would just have to wait for it. But can anyone suggest any alternative? I'm willing to consider more drastic options and I don't mind losing recent local change to my files.

Comment: I have had very similar issues with Dropbox recently and I am starting to get fed up with the client.  I hope you get an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other guy mentions, the best way to get Dropbox working correctly again is to just blow everything away and start over.

[Quote](http://m.wikihow.com/Unlink-a-Computer-from-a-Dropbox-Account#Windows)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[Quote](http://welovegadgets123.blogspot.com/2014/02/how-to-uninstall-dropbox-and-complete.html?m=1)

Uninstalling the Desktop Application on Mac OS X

- Quit Dropbox (click on the Dropbox icon from the menu bar, click on
  the gear icon, selectPreferences... and then "Quit Dropbox").
- Drag-and-drop Dropbox to the trash from your Applications folder.
- Your Dropbox folder and its contents will remain intact. However, if
  you'd like to remove that as well, you can *drag and drop your Dropbox
  folder to the trash.*

Make sure to perform that last step. Your files are still "safe" in the the cloud. Download and reinstall Dropbox as new.

Answer (score 1):

You can unlink your account, delete the dropbox folder and link the account again.

Comment: Hmm... are you sure that will work? I have tried unlinking and relinking the client before (not deleting the folder) but it made no difference.

Comment: How does one do that precisely?

Comment: @RGWinston It works, I have tried it. You must delete the folder though.